# Oracle connection in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have a ASP.NET (.NET 4.0) application which implements Rest Services. I am connecting to Oracle in this application. My code works fine as under. Please note its in the constructor.

```
OracleConnection m_cnn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=MySid;User Id=user1;Password=password1");
m_cnn.Open();
//m_connected = ConnectCDB();
```

Now I change my code as below and I get an null pointer exception

```
OracleConnection m_cnn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=MySid;User Id=user1;Password=password1");
//m_cnn.Open();
m_connected = ConnectCDB();
```

The ConnectCDB function is

```
private bool ConnectCDB()
{
   // Open the database connection
   m_cnn.Open();

   return true;
}
```

The m_cnn and m_connected are private members of the class. Why should it give error if I call a separate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
OracleConnection m_cnn = new OracleConnection("...");
```

... declares a *local* variable inside the constructor. It's not assigning a value to the *instance* variable. To do that, you should use:

```
m_cnn = new OracleConnection("...");
```

Having said that, I'd be wary of this pattern anyway - it's generally better to create, open, use and then close connections as and when you need them. It makes it simpler to clean up properly, without implementing `IDisposable` all over the place. Rely on the underlying connection pooling to make it efficient.

Comment: ops... very silly mistake on my side. Thanks for pointing this.

Comment: Do you mean I should Open, Use and close an Oracle connection everytime the user calls the Service (which could be every 1-2 seconds) and not keep a connection open?

Comment: @user2837961: Yes, absolutely. The connection pool will keep it efficient, and you won't need to worry about accidentally using the same connection twice concurrently.